# How to remove # in my browser window and how to change dynamic url in my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash

HI i m creating a site   i have face two problum

my site is `rohitazad.com`

1. is how to remove `#tag` in my site

if i click to profile link in my menu item top bar than my url is `http://rohitazad.com/#/profile`  but mya be this possible i remove my # and my url `http://rohitazad.com/profile` is this.

2. if i scoll my site example i reach the profile section than my navigation is active and may be possible my url is change dynamic `http://rohitazad.com/profile`

**[As like this](http://www.webbyawards.com/winners/2013)**

Answer (score 1):

In the [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) article is a section called **Adding and modifying history entries** - read about this.

Especially useful is `pushState()` method that change window url and title without page reload.

Be careful, you can only add sth to history, edit current or read it, but never delete.

Referring to the example:

```
history.replaceState(null, "example title", "foo_bar.html");
```